# Oracle installation recovery

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, recovery

I have an oracle 11g R2 installation on Drive D, and OS installation on drive C. (Windows Server 2012)

The OS installation is somehow broken and we needed to reinstall windows on drive c. Is there any way to re-register oracle components and run the oracle services on drive D? The machine name is the same as before. I couldn't find any options regarding this on installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin and run below command for cloning of oracle home.

```
setup  -clone -silent -defaultHomeName ORACLE_HOME=<oracle home path> oracle_home_name=<home_name> oracle_base=<oracle_base_path>
```

below is link for the details.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/app_cloning.htm#LADBI430

Comment: thanks but i suppose this only clones database software. I need to run my database as before the OS reinstall.

Comment: To register your database oradim is utility. $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oradim -new SID. Also use netca for configuration of listener.

Comment: thanks. After using oradim utility, a registery tweek must be applied in order to start database after service start.

Comment: Yes... Go to regedit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE-->SOFTWARE--> Oracle-> ORACLE_HOME_NAME and set ORACLE_SID_AUTOSTART=true, ORACLE_SID_SHUTDOWN=true, ORACLE_SID_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=90, ORACLE_SID_SHUTDOWNTYPE=immediate.

Comment: Hi Sarica, Did you find my answer useful? If yes please vote up.